# angular for loop returns last value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I believe this is a pretty simple question and I have found some solutions here on forum but it looks that I did everything right but still getting only last value. I've wrote this simple **[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rlmbLz2TUFiqRy0kKa46)**. Somebody could explain me, where is my mistake?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Reinforcement';

                    $http.get('test.json')
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.test = data;
                        });


      $scope.getName = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.test.length; i++) {
               $scope.parent = $scope.test[i].name
            }
         }
});
```

html

```
   <div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li ng-repeat="objName in test" ng-click="getName()">
                                                    <a href=""> {{objName.name}}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                </div>

                                {{ parent }}
```

Comment: In your example the dropdown contains all of the elements listed in the json file. What is the problem you struggle with?

Comment: @SayusiAndo  if you click on "Monopoly", it returns "World", this is my struggling

Comment: why -1? this question is good for angular beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat` `$index` to get name. 
Don't loop over your model, see it is more simple :

```
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

<div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="objName in test" ng-click="getName($index)">
        <a href="">       {{objName.name}}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>

{{ selectedCategory }}


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.name = 'Reinforcement';

 $http.get('test.json')
     .success(function (data) {
      $scope.test = data;
 });

 $scope.getName = function (index) {
   console.info($scope.test[index].name);
   $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.test[index].name;
 }
});
```

NOTE/advice : avoid using model name like `parent` since you could confuse with `$parent` which gives access to parent scope.

**In your second case, you have to get parent $index with `$parent.$index` (*since nested ng-reapeat*) but it is the same trick = no loop over array model:**

**html:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="entity in entitis" >
            <a class="trigger right-caret">{{ entity }}</a>
            <ul ng-if="entity | filter : 'Main'" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="domain in ast" ng-click="getDomain($parent.$index, $index)">
                    <a href=""> {{domain.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>    
 {{ items }}
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <p><b>parent index : {{astParentIndex}}</b></p>
 <p><b>index : {{astIndex}}</b></p>
```

**js**

```
  $scope.getDomain = function (parentIndex, index) {
    $scope.astParentIndex = parentIndex;
    $scope.astIndex = index;
    $scope.items = $scope.ast[parentIndex].children;
  }
```

Comment: thank for answer, so does index work even in nested arrays?

Comment: $index is related to your ng-repeat that loops over an array model. So it would be easier to better answer your question with use-cases (*since I'm not sure to offer a good answer*). But another advice, when you need the first or the last item of an array model use better $first and $last. See angular website it is super well documented.

Comment: Nested array suppose you use another ng-repeat inside ng-reapeat. I guess you talked about that?

Comment: right, so basically I'm trying to load child array in ibjecxt, and every time getting only last array, then I have found that for loop returns only last object and wasn't lucky so decided ask about it

Comment: Please provide a piece of code I'm sure it will be fixed fast. I understand ng-repeat can be tricky at a first sight but it is simple when you understand the `behind the scene`. Keep on learning that is super nice and worth you will see

Comment: thank you so much for explanation I fix it by myself

Comment: Sorry (need to sleep at night^^) I updated comment for you above plunker in comment. Use `$parent.$index` and `$index`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$index` into your `getName()` method.

**Your HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="objName in test track by $index" ng-click="getName($index)">
        <a href=""> {{objName.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>                                 
{{ bindedVariable}}
</body>
```

**Your Controller**

Then use the index of the selected object to get the correct value from the `$scope.test` array.

```
$scope.getName = function (index) {
  $scope.bindedVariable= $scope.test[index].name
}
```

Comment: don't need to track by $index to use $index. track by just helps for performance.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.parent = $scope.test[i].name`

This will overwrite `$scope.parent` every single time, thus it will only ever be the last value

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you ng-repeat item as a parameter to `getName` (but I suggest you call it `setName` or `selectName` which would be more readable):

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li ng-repeat="objName in test" ng-click="getName(objName.name)">
                                                    <a href=""> {{objName.name}}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                </div>

                                {{ parent }}
</body>

</html>
```

## JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Reinforcement';

                    $http.get('test.json')
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.test = data;
                        });


      $scope.getName = function (name) {
               $scope.parent = name;
         }
});
```

## Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/p3PFmQHFmllcXEvL7K0z

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop always sets `$scope.parent` to the last element. Try this:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in test" ng-click="getName(obj)">
    <a href="">{{obj.name}}</a>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getName = function(obj) {
    $scope.parent = obj.name;
}
```